# JFrame minimize to another JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a class which extends `JFrame`.
The steps which I am going to do after I run my code are:

1. Minimize the program
2. Click on the icon of the program from docker to reload it

Now, I would like it to display another frame to be shown while keeping the previous frame `setVisible` to *false*. The new frame is basically a login page where after I type in a password will it show the window which was previously minimized.

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: As of now, I've designed and coded the frames.

Comment: so you haven't tried anything yet

Comment: It might be a nicer approach to just switch panels within the one JFrame, see the [CardLayout docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) The usual way to approach a log-in is to show a modal `JDialog` or a `JOptionPane` in front of the frame.